# array of object into array of object but different (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Using javascript, I have this array:

```
people = [{name: carlo, lastname: Garcia, age: 28},
          {name: maria, lastname: pia, age: 20},
          {name: elly, lastname: martinez, age: 25}]
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
arrayList = [{data: {name: carlo, lastname: garcia, age: 28}, checked: false},
             {data: {name: carlo, lastname: garcia, age: 28}, checked: false},
             {data: {name: carlo, lastname: garcia, age: 28}, checked: false}]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `Array.prototype.map`

```js
var people = [{ name: "carlo", lastname: "Garcia", age: 28 }, { name: "maria", lastname: "pia", age: 20 }, { name: "elly", lastname: "martinez", age: 25 }]
var arrayList = people.map(person => ({
    data: person,
    checked: false,
}))
console.log(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map()`. Return an object with `data` and `checked` fields.

Where:

- `data` is set to each `person`
- `checked` is set to `false`

```js
people = [{name: 'carlo', lastname: 'Garcia', age: 28},{name: 'maria', lastname: 'pia', age: 20},{name: 'elly', lastname: 'martinez', age: 25}]

arrayList = people.map(p => ({ data: p, checked: false }))

console.log(arrayList)
```